# Issue while creating columns in document libraries using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using below script to iterate through each document library and create a column with the value equals to the name of library itself:

```
   $ver = $host | select version 

if($Ver.version.major -gt 1) {$Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"} 

if(!(Get-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea 0)) 

{ 

Write-Progress -Activity "Loading Modules" -Status "Loading Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" 

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 

} 





$SourceWebURL = "http://sitecollection/sites/sitename" 





$ssite = Get-SPSite $SourceWebURL

$sweb = $ssite.OpenWeb("Op")



foreach($slist in $sweb.Lists) 

{

    if($slist.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")

            {

                        $spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text

                        $sList.Fields.Add("OpCo",$spFieldType,$true)

                        $field = $sList.Fields["OpCoName"]

                        $field.DefaultValue = $slist.Title

                        $field.Update()

                        $sList.Update()

            }

}
```

I am getting below error:

```
An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Collection was modifi
ed; enumeration operation may not execute..
At C:\Users\abc.ps1:31 char:8
+ foreach <<<< ($slist in $sweb.Lists)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Share...on+SPEnumer
   ator:SPEnumerator) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadEnumeration
```

Comment: What do you mean with assign a value? Your code is only adding the field to the list. You can not add a value to the field itself, you need to add values to individual list items. Or do you want to set a default-value?

Comment: I want to add value to newly created column. Its a default value for a particular library equals to library name itself

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11009/set-default-value-in-a-document-library-column-via-powershell

Comment: I have modified the code

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting seems to be related to processing the collection rather than setting the default value. You should investigate a better way to get your lists that won't modify the collection as you process it. Here is a rough example:

```
$ssite = Get-SPSite $SourceWebURL

$sweb = $ssite.OpenWeb("Op")

#Get the URLs for the lists we want to process
$listUrls = $sweb.Lists | Where-Object { $_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary"} | Select DefaultViewURL

foreach($listURL in $listUrls) 

{
    #Get instance of the list, not associated with a collection
    $sList = $sweb.GetList($listURL)
    $spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text

    $sList.Fields.Add("OpCo",$spFieldType,$true)

    $field = $sList.Fields["OpCoName"]

    $field.DefaultValue = $slist.Title

    $field.Update()

    $sList.Update()           

}
```